# Error :Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: vb.net

**Tengo lo siguiente**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Partial Public Class Principal
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim idrequest As String
    Dim conexion As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dictamen").ConnectionString
    Dim encontro As Boolean

    End Sub
```

*cuando lo ejecuto pasa lo siguiente*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tengo lo siguiente en el web config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="dictamen" connectionString= "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source= 192.168.3.2;Password=dictanav2019;User ID=dictamenes;Initial Catalog=Dictamenes" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>


  </connectionStrings>
```

**Urgente :c**

Manda el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]